# fig, ax displaying all plots in one

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I am doing some visualization in Google Colabs with pyplot and seaborn.

Trying use fig, axes to get 6 plots but on testing I get all plots in one. Any ideas as of why? Is it a Colabs problem or is it me?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,3,figsize=(15,10))
axes[0] = plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
axes[1] = plt.plot([2, 2, 3, 4])
axes[2] = plt.plot([3, 2, 3, 4])
axes[3] = plt.plot([4, 2, 3, 4])
axes[4] = plt.plot([5, 2, 3, 4])
axes[5] = plt.plot([6, 2, 3, 4])
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB4Sw.png)

Been trying to google and searching stack but without finding a solution.

Kindly
Andy

Comment: It's unclear why you added the Seaborn tag to the post.  For Seaborn's axes-level functions you need e.g. `sns.histplot(..., ax=axes[0,0])`.  Figure-level functions, e.g. `sns.catplot(...)` create their own figure and subplots.

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry I see that now. I'm planning on using the seaborn lmplot but just tried it out with a plt plot to see how it acted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `.plot` method on the Axis objects:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(15,10))
axes[0, 0].plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
axes[0, 1].plot([2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
axes[1, 0].plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
axes[1, 1].plot([2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes i surprise myself with my stupidity :P saved me!